# LiveWire PowerGrid - auto update table (remove item) after delete

Tags: laravel-livewire, livewire-powergrid

I have following code:

```
/**
     * PowerGrid Skill Action Buttons.
     *
     * @return array<int, Button>
     */
    public function actions(): array
    {
       return [
           Button::make('edit', 'Edit')
               ->class('bg-indigo-500 cursor-pointer text-white px-3 py-2.5 m-1 rounded text-sm')
               ->route('admin.skill.edit', ['skill' => 'id']),

           Button::make('destroy', 'Delete')
                ->class('bg-red-500 cursor-pointer text-white px-3 py-2 m-1 rounded text-sm')
                ->emit('actionDelete', ['skill' => 'id'])
        ];
    }

#[NoReturn] public function actionDelete(Skill $skill): void
    {
        $this->openModal = true;
        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('actionDelete', [
            'link' => route('admin.skill.destroy', ['skill' => $skill]),
            'title' => $skill->name,
            'token' => csrf_token(),
        ]);
    }

public static function delete($id): void
    {
        Skill::find($id)->delete();
    }
```

After delete is performed, the table is not auto updated (item should be removed). Item is deleted from the DB. What am I doing wrong here?